# Coss origin Error

Tags: shopify

I'm getting the following error in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Headers I've used are:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
```

But I'm still stuck.The error i am getting is as follows-

> Image from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example-app.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: are you using ajax crossdomain?

Comment: I dont know but when it is in mozilla no error occurs but other then mozilla i got that error.(i am using php for development)